# asp.net app still using old data after SSIS Package updates it

Tags: asp.net, ssis

I have got a SSIS Package running every 2 hours. It collects data from different DBs and updates the DB of my ASP.Net Application. Everything goes smooth, but the asp.net application is still using the old data, it has the data somehow cached. If I just  open save the web.config, it empties the cache and uses the updated new data. How can I make sure, that the app empties the cache after SSIS Package finished successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your code then you should use [SqlCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx). If not then you can add special aspx page and call it from SSIS. This page can refresh cached data.

Comment: I will try both what do you mean by a special aspx page

Comment: Special means the main purpose for this page is refreshing cache. You should be careful on this because of security vulnerability. Better will be SqlCacheDependency.